# Origen y uso de la expresión "fe del carbonero"

Tags: expresiones, historia

Ayer descubrí la expresión:

> Tener la fe del carbonero.

Por el contexto, entendí que podía querer decir algo así como: confiar en algo ciegamente, y/o a pesar de las razones en contra. Hoy, con una búsqueda en Google que me devuelve, entre otras, [esta](https://enroquedeciencia.blogspot.com/2014/04/por-que-se-dice-tener-la-fe-del.html) y [esta](http://reflexionesdemanuel.blogspot.com/2010/04/nuestra-lengua-la-fe-del-carbonero.html) páginas explicando su significado, veo que más bien significa: creer lo mismo que creen los demás, sin entrar a analizarlo. Un significado parecido al que supuse, y que también cuadra con el contexto, pero con el matiz de "lo mismo que los demás"; es decir, que no aplicaría a una persona que esté ella sola convencida de algo, por ejemplo. (También confirmo que lo primero que pensé al leer "[carbonero](https://www.seo.org/ave/carbonero-comun-2/)" no tiene, en principio, nada que ver con la frase :P)

Aclarado el significado, e insatisfecho respecto de las anécdotas indicadas en algunas de las páginas para explicar este dicho, pregunto: ¿cuál es el origen de esta frase? ¿Se entiende igual en todas las zonas de habla hispana?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

El [***Diccionario de anécdotas, dichos, ilustraciones, locuciones y refranes***](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=25PDT_i0rEQC&pg=PA311&lpg=PA311&dq="fe+del+carbonero") (p.311) menciona dos orígenes propuestos, siendo la más probable la misma anécdota que la de San Patricio de Irlanda y el [*shamrock*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shamrock):

> #### 1. La fe del carbonero.
>
> Esta expresión tan repetida por Unamuno en la *Agonía del Cristanismo*, quiere decir la fe sencilla y firme de los simples de corazón, la fe del que no exige pruebas ni sabe de argumentos.
>
> **El origen del dicho lo explica el maestro Correas en su *Vocabulario de Refranes***, al comentar la frase: «Yo creo lo que cree el carbonero», en la forma siguiente:
>
> > Un maestro teólogo tuvo una vez plática con un carbonero en cosas de fe y acerca de la Santísima Trinidad..., y propuso al carbonero:
> >
> > —«¿Cómo entendéis vos eso de las tres divinas personas, tres y una?».
> >
> > El carbonero tomó la falda del sayo e hizo tres dobleces, y luego, extendiéndola, dijo:
> >
> > —«Así», mostrando que eran tres cosas y todas una. Agradóle al teólogo y satisfizose y después, al tiempo de su muerte, decía:
> >
> > —«Creo lo que cree el carbonero».
>
> **Según Batús, el origen del dicho se encuentra en el siguiente cuento** que se lee en las *Memorias* de Trevoux:
>
> > Había un carbonero, exclusiva y constantemente ocupado en su oficio, a quien parece que el diablo había tomado por su cuenta. Un día, disfrazado el diablo de doctor de Sorbona, la emprendió de frente y preguntóle qué creía él acerca de la fe de Jesucristo, y el buen hombre le contestó:
> >
> > —«Yo creo lo que cree la Iglesia».
> >
> > Entonces el diablo, apremiándole de nuevo, le dijo:
> >
> > —«Y bien, ¿qué cree la Iglesia?».
> >
> > A la cual el carbonero contestó, dejando confundido y patitieso a aquel maligno espíritu:
> >
> > —«Ella cree todo lo que creo yo».
>
> La verdadera explicación parece ser la de Correas.